# TextMate : Keeping my KeyBindings after an update

Tags: textmate, keybindings

I'm using TextMate 2 with some custom KeyBindings. I change them in `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict`. It works great, but everytime I update them app they get reset. (I guess the update replace the whole .app).

Any suggestion how I could prevent that (= not set again my keybindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under [MacroMates](http://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings.html)' keyBindings page is written:

> In addition TextMate has a `/path/‍to/‍TextMate.app/‍Contents/‍Resources/‍KeyBindings.dict` file with some extra key bindings which are specific to TextMate (and thus not appropriate to put in the per user global key bindings file). **You can copy this file to** `~/Library/‍Application Support/‍TextMate` 
>   **and edit it, this will then take precedence over the bundled file.**

As this file won't be replaced during the Application's *update*, your keybindings will remain.

**Note**: As Matthieu points out, you will need to rename the file to `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` to make it work.

Comment: I had to rename it `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` to make it work. You should edit your answer which wasn't clear on that ;)